# 2 level drop down menu with existing template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

thanks in advance if you can help

http://www.portnine.com/bootstrap/AircraftAdmin/

we have purchased this template and have developed our admin panel using this template but it has come time that we need the menu up the top right to be 2 levels, is there anyone who could maybe hint me in the direction of adding another level or show me the code so i can understand where to start

i have sent the developer an email but have not received a reply as of yet its been 2 weeks

and help is very apreciated

**edit**
i would very much love it, if it could do this, so when i scroll over users it pops up a new window to the left

[image]

```
<ul id='main-menu' class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
                <li class='dropdown hidden-xs'>
                        <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>
                                <span class='padding-right-small' style='position:relative;top: 3px;'></span>LEVEL 1
                                    <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>

                                                     <li class='dropdown'><a href='#' data-toggle='dropdown'>Users</a>
                                                        <ul class='dropdown menu'>
                                                           <li><a>link 1</a><li>
                                                           <li><a>link 2</a><li>
                                                           <li><a>link 3</a><li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </li>

                        </ul>
                </li>
        </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you take screen shot and mark the changes what exactly you need to change on that page?(using paint)

Answer (score 1):

okay so you just need to add a class of dropdown if you want to add your second level dropdown on users. 
Here is what I have done below if your dropdown's second level will be for users

```
 <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Users</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
       <li><a>link 1</a><li>
       <li><a>link 2</a><li>
       <li><a>link 3</a><li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: tried this with the new code above and it doesnt work, ill update my post, with code and screenshot

Comment: instead of dropdown menu, use dropdown-menu. it should work @Nathan. Just edited my post

Comment: changed it to dropdown-menu and now it only displays users but when i scroll over it does nothing @Code Enthusiast

Comment: @Nathan try changing dropdown-menu to dropdown-submenu like i just edited in my code

Comment: just changed it to dropdown-submenu and it goes back to doing the same thing as the second photo above should i be creating something in the css for dropdown-submenu

Comment: Working on it actually found interresting stuff you might want to check out these questions:http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-dropdowns.php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344596/bootstrap-dropdown-within-dropdown

Comment: awesome ill wait to see what you come up with and ill have a browse of those

Answer (score 1):

I found what you need.

Much like jsfiddle but built exclusively for bootstrap.

http://www.bootply.com/RSD/0gMDXQS8uk

Comment: this doesnt display anthing other than navbar for me

Comment: Are placing inside an actual navbar that is already set up. I think that is what all of us are assuming you already have.

Comment: any chance you could copy your .dropdown-submenu code ?

Comment: I edited my answer. Have a look at that link. My template is so heavily modified, I would need to give you two are three hundred line of css, and a js file or two. This is pure bootstrap that you have. No premium modification like what I gave you. I apologize

Comment: i have gotten to this stage but cannot make the menu apear right http://www.bootply.com/mP3jrGlmXY# so for now im going to give up

Comment: You just have to know how to use google my friend

http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/szx4Y/51/